# Showing that an equation has no solution in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Show that $x^3 + 10x^2 + 6x + 2 = 0$ has no solutions in $\Bbb Z$.

This seems rather trivial to do but I don't know how to rigorously show this is true. Having graphed this and attempted to factor,I see that it is indeed true. Could someone please explain how I would go about showing this rigorously?

Comment: Are you familiar with Eisenstein's Criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion )?  There's a very obvious prime to try here.  The Rational Root Theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem ) is another natural choice, though for that you'll have to do a small, finite amount of work.  These two should be your starting point for any question of polynomial reducibility or roots.

Comment: Suppose I use the rational root theorem. Then I would have solutions of the form $ \pm \frac{2}{1}$. And I know $2$ is prime. Where would I go from here? @user26857

Comment: So then if I don't get $0$ with any of the four options for $x$ then it would show by rational root theorem that it has not solutions in $\Bbb Z$ or just in $\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. $x\in\mathbb Z$ and $x^3 + 10x^2 + 6x + 2 = 0$ $\implies x\mid 2$

Answer (score 3):

What is the context? Another way you could show this is rely on the fact the irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ implies irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$, provided that $p$ does not divide the leading coefficient of your polynomial. Selecting $p = 3$, your polynomial reduces to $\tilde{f} = x^3 + x^2 + 2$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is relatively small, we can check each element to see if it is a root or not:

1. $\tilde{f}(0) = 0^3 + 0^2 + 2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$
2. $\tilde{f}(1) = 1^3 + 1^2 + 2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$
3. $\tilde{f}(2) = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$

Hence $\tilde{f}$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, which implies there are no solutions to the equation $x^3 +10x + 6x + 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ as well as $\mathbb{Z}$.